# Angular Material dark and light theme toggle not being applied throughout application

Tags: angular, angular-material

I implemented this theme toggle here: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-themes-material-so?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

It almost works. The themes are applied globally when toggled, but it does not overwrite everything in the app. Here is a before and after (Most of the UI had to be blurred):

**LIGHT THEME TOGGLED**

[image]

**DARK THEME TOGGLED**

[image]

- The red outline on top shows that the input control was toggled to
  dark.
- The middle red outline shows the dark background on the tab-group.
- The lowest red outline shows the table checkboxes toggled to white.

The body of the app also toggles to the dark background, but you cannot see it here as the sidnav is filling that space. Other questions on stackoverflow seem to experience the opposite issue I am having. Their body/font/dialogs do not change, but all of mine do. My dialogs / input controls are dark themed, but almost nothing else is. I have a feeling it has to do with my sidnav / router setup.

Comment: If you statically set any of the themes for your app, does it work fine?

Comment: @GCSDC Yes it does. It is only when I try to add a user toggle that it does this.

Answer (score 0):

The stackblitz which you provided was helpful, the only thing noticeable was the "basic button" there which kept in red color and didn't switch colors; Upon investigation we see:

- In inspect element, on **dark** background, we see the button as:
  `.custom-theme .mat-button.mat-warn { color: #f44336; }`
- In inspect element, on **light** theme, we see the button as:
  `.light-custom-theme .mat-button.mat-warn { color: #f44336; }`
- in your **light-custom-theme.scss**, you have defined red for warning
  `$light-custom-theme-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);`
- in your **custom-theme.scss**, you have **also** defined red for warning
  `$light-custom-theme-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);`

I [forked your stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-themes-material-so-auwipz) to make a change in custom-theme.scss, it now has yellow as the color for warnings against the dark/custom theme

Comment: I appreciate the response, but that is not the issue here. I simply followed that stackblitz as a guide to implement it into my own application. In the screenshots above, my application does not behave as expected. The dark theme does not get applied to most of my app when the toggle is used. If I manually change the dark/light flag in my custom theme and then recompile, the theme works as expected both ways.

Comment: Hi @CAlex, can you share the code for your site? or share a MVCE for it...